# Comparing unsigned, including metavalues, to a bit pattern

Tags: vhdl

I am writing a VHDL process that needs to compare an input value to zero. The input may contain metavalues ('U', 'X', 'L', 'H', etc.), in which case zero should not be asserted.

Unfortunately, ModelSim issues a warning with each comparison:

```
# ** Warning: NUMERIC_STD."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
#    Time: 14 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /tb/uut
```

Any ideas on how to code the below in order to avoid such warnings? Turning off numeric_std warnings globally is not an option.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity Test is
    port (
        clk               : in std_logic;
        reset             : in std_logic;

        i_in_data         : in unsigned(31 downto 0);

        o_out_zero        : out std_logic
    );
end Test;

architecture rtl of Test is
begin
    process(clk, reset) begin
        if(reset='1') then
            o_out_zero <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(i_in_data = (i_in_data'range=>'0')) then
                o_out_zero <= '1';
            else
                o_out_zero <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: The appropriate answer will depend on whether this entity is to be synthesisable, and is expected to work correctly in the presence of metavalues there... if these "metavalues" warnings clear in the first few clock cycles (say up to 200ns) , it is quite usual to ignore them. Any after that may be flagging a real design problem you want to fix before synthesis...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I usually force metavalues ('x') in simulation whenever a data value is not valid. Normally this aids in debugging, since it is then easy to see invalid data values during simulation. In the presented case, I actually don't care what the value of o_out_zero is in the presence of metavalues, since it is discarded in later stages. I just want to describe the check for zero in a synthesizeable way without additional overhead and no simulation warnings, such that after synthesis data=0 outputs '1', and anything else outputs '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output of `o_out_zero` doesn't matter in the presence of metavalues, then the useful function `to_01` from numeric_std can be used to eliminate them in the comparison expression. See also to_01xz etc for similar purposes...

Replace

```
if(i_in_data = (i_in_data'range=>'0')) then
```

with

```
if to_01(i_in_data) = (i_in_data'range=>'0') then
```

and it should be good.

You do know that parentheses around the boolean expressions in an if-statement are unnecessary, right? The less VHDL looks like C, the better...

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I know parentheses are unnecessary in quite a few spots in VHDL, but I don't necessarily agree that C-like VHDL is a bad thing... Any specific reasons, other than that it possibly prevents people from falling into a sequential coding mindset?

Comment: As an added bonus, this also allows the statment to be written as `if to_01(i_in_data) = 0 then`

Comment: only personal opinion, but when I'm writing VHDL I like to be reminded that I'm free of C's absurd limitations. Well done on noticing "=0", there's useful stuff in that library!